# Solid-state Electronic switch for low level signals

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, switches, ttl

I need a very simple circuit to connect a signal to one of two ways like this:

[image]

My *com* signal is actually a microphone input, so very low voltage, **<200mV**, how can I make a solid state switch that not interfere with the low voltage signal? So *com* can go to L1 or L2 with no distortion. Im planning to actuate the switch with TTL voltage.

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:

- You can use e.g. an analog switch/MUX like the [4053](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4053B.pdf).
- If the signal you want to switch is a pure AC signal you might also be able to use a   diode that is switched between forward and reversed biased. See for example [here in section "Analog Switch"](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_3/10.html). This method is often used with signals in the RF range.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dedicated analog MUX, as stated above, would probably be the best solution. You can, however, build it from discrete components. Following circuit *should* do the job. Each switch (otherwise known as a *transmission gate*) consists of two MOSFETs, P- and N-Channel respectively. It is activated by applying *VCC* to N-FET's gate and by pulling P's gate to *GND*. Applying voltages in the opposite order will disable the switch. That's what the inverter's doing (it can be realized by two MOSFET's as well).

*Note that this is only guaranteed to work when used in the form of an off-the-shelf IC. It may or may not work when bodged together using discrete CMOS*

[image: analog MUX schematic]

It will function properly - more or less linearly - if the *INPUT* voltages remain below *VCC - Vth*, where Vth is the switch-on threshold voltage of the MOSFET's.

Comment: You should mention that these are called transmission gates; building a transmission gate on a wafer makes sense because you have localized impurities/etc, but out of discrete components there might be an issue with matching - not sure, would have to check.

Answer (score 2):

The electronic solutions proposed are fine and will do what you want. However, if you want a more generic and flexible solution I'd consider using a decent quality reed relay. You are not limited with supply rails in this method and the input can be totally floating and isolated from your control voltage.

[Here](http://www.pickeringrelays.com/pdfs/100.pdf) is a decent offering from Pickering relays. It can be driven from TTL and is suitable for switching thermocouple inputs (this means it will be fine for low level audio signals too).

[image]

Comment: I also thought about (reed) relays but the OP explicitly asked for a *solid state* switch.

Comment: @Curd that's why I began my answer suggesting the electronic proposals are fine. I'm offering this answer up in case the OP hasn't considered that sealed reed relays are a viable alternative to solid-state switching - given that he wants to switch a microphone signal (which might also be a balanced signal and contain 48V phantom power) I thought it appropriate but yes, it aint solid-state for sure.